# Using Immutable.js without Flux or Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux, immutable.js

I've been messing around with some code and I think I just realized something stupid. Using Immutable.js in React without Flux or Redux is a fool's errand.

```
toggleTask(task) {
    const found = _.find(this.state.taskList, task => task.name === task);
    found.isDone = !found.isCompleted;
    const index = _.findIndex(this.state.taskList, task => task.name === task);

    const temp = Immutable.fromJS(this.state.taskList);
    temp.setIn([index, 'isDone'], found.isDone).toJS();

    this.setState({ taskList: temp.toJS() });

}
```

So basically before I realized how much of a fool I was I was making an Immutable object, changed it using Immutable.js methods and then changed it back to an array. It's useless, because shallow compare should work without immutable objects.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {

    return (this.props.name !== nextProps.name || this.props.priority !== nextProps.priority || this.props.isDone !== nextProps.isDone  );
}
```

I've been using lodash methods, but since I am comparing the props individually and because they're primitives (primitives like strings and booleans can't be immutables anyways), I don't think it really matters and it would probably have worked even if I didn't use them.

```
toggleTask(task) {
    const found = _.find(this.state.taskList, task => task.name === task);
    found.isDone = !found.isDone;
    this.setState({ taskList: this.state.taskList });
}
```

So am I wrong to say that Immutable.js in React is useless without Redux or Flux? Is there something I am not understanding correctly? I've watched examples and they didn't quite make sense to me since I've never used Flux or Redux.

Comment: You are not using the library correctly... nothing to do with Flux/Redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're actually on the right track. The reason why Immutable.js is more useful with Redux/Flux is because Immutable.js allows you to make inexpensive shallow comparisons with deeply-nested json objects. That's its main advantage. In your case, I suspect you have a simple todo application where your state is a list of simple arrays, in that case you don't get anything from using Immutable.js, because you can just compare the properties, which isn't expensive. You may not need it in a Redux application either, but in large project you may often have very big deeply nested json objects, in that case Immutable.js is extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

`Immutable` has nothing to do with Redux or Flux.

You can use Flux and Redux without `Immutable` and you can use `Immutable` without Flux and Redux.

`Immutable` helps promoting a good programming style based on immutable data structures. That's all. Such a programming style goes very well with functional programming and with React.

`Immutable` is not the only framework out there doing the same. Javascript has its own `Object.freeze` method that makes an object immutable without additional containers. You can also use [icepick](https://github.com/aearly/icepick) and others.

Comment: But it's useless since you can't use setState with an Immutable object.

Comment: @aLex Why do you think you cannot use `setState` with an immutable object?

Comment: Because it doesn't work unless I convert it back to a javascript object with toJS().

Comment: What exactly does not work? React does not care what you save into `state`. Please update the question with code that does not work.